# Parallel Li-po battery and load with simple charger

Tags: battery-charging, charger, lipo

I am building my first battery powered board, powered by a 14.8 V Li-po battery. I want to allow the user to continue using the device while charging the battery, and have been reading about load sharing circuits [here](https://www.microtype.io/lithium-ion-battery-charger-circuit-load-sharing/) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/470442/charging-battery-with-external-charger-while-powering-load).

My understanding of these precautions is that we want to avoid putting the battery and load in parallel since it makes it impossible for the external charger to track how many Ah have been delivered to the battery which can confound the charging algorithm. I know what charger I will be using, however, and I'm pretty sure it's kind of a dumb charger. The charger is shown in an image below.

The charger indicates charging (red) vs charged/disconnected (green) on it, which leads me to believe it is only monitoring the amount of current being delivered to decide if the battery has charged, and is otherwise just current/voltage limited.

I have two questions about this:

1. Is the circuit below OK for the battery/charger/load distribution if the charger is just a simple power supply?
2. Is it a reasonable assumption that the charger here is just a simple power supply, and not a more sophisticated charger?

[image: Power Distribution Circuit]

[image: Battery Charger]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple power supply might cause a Li-po battery to explode if it tries charging the Li-po because voltage and the current might be too high.

If you have a REAL charger designed for the battery then it will probably try to overcharge the Li-po when the charger is also powering a load. A Li-po must NEVER be overcharged.

Answer (score 1):

There are devices which combine Li-Po charging with switching the system load between DC adapter input or battery supply. E.g. the Texas Instruments [BQ25798](https://www.ti.com/product/BQ25798) which supports a Li-Po battery with 1 to 4 cells. Since you mention a *14.8 V Li-po battery* guessing that contains 4 cells.

The Simplified Schematic is:

[image: BQ25798 Simplified Schematic]

How much power can your load draw, since that will impact the selection of a suitable charger / load distribution circuit?

Comment: This is the direction I'm starting to go now, I'd love to use one that has relatively few external components like the one you have there, but I'm not seeing any in stock, at least at JLC where I'm doing pick and place. Working through designing  around the BQ25713, since they have it, but the BOM is getting huge lol. My load draws a max of 100W.